# MongoDB Sorting With $or Query

Tags: mongodb, sorting

My documents look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "55ef27bbe2be7b1e618ed863",
  "creator": "55f082dfbec88fe26f65f522",
  "privacy": "public"
}
```

I want to get all documents that fit these criteria:

1. Created by a certain user.
2. Public documents.
3. All documents with a certain id.

So my query looks like this:

```
{
  "$or": [
    { "creator": "55f082dfbec88fe26f65f522" },
    { "privacy": "public" },
    { "_id:": $in: ["55f3128043a933b555921e20"] }
  ]
}
```

But I want to sort the documents so that the ones created by 55f082dfbec88fe26f65f522 are at the top.

How would I do that?